# macOS - docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, macos, installation, package

After successfully installing docker using home brew here with the command `brew install docker`

Per this instruction - https://www.cprime.com/resources/blog/docker-for-mac-with-homebrew-a-step-by-step-tutorial/

The location is here - `/usr/local/bin/docker`

With version - `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c70180f`

I am unable to start it to run a container, when I try the `hello-world` example I am getting the error - `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`

I also cannot find the application using spotlight or in the applications folder.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like docker not running. What method do you use to install docker and check if Docker is running?

Comment: I used home brew - ```brew install docker```. When I check for a location and a version and it seems to be installed correctly with ```Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c70180f```. Though when I try to run any container, I just tried ```hello-world``` I'm getting the error  ```cannot connect to daemon``` so it doesn't seem to be running on my machine. I tried to find the app also and it's not showing up in my applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Docker using home brew was not enough, I needed to install the docker desktop application too and run the container from there.